# Quarkus + Angular in JavaVM not working after deployment

Tags: angular, quarkus

I created a Quarkus app for my backend. In the folder `src/main/angular` I created an Angular app for my frontend. When I build my Angular app, the files are stored in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`. Then I start my Quarkus app with `mvn clean quarkus:dev` and everything works fine. My frontend is accessible and so is the backend.

My problem start when I create an image of the app using JVM to deploy on it Kubernetes. The backend is still accessible, but for the frontend I get a `404`. I checked the deployed `.jar` file and it contains my frontend files.

What am I missing? Is the any special setting that I forgot? Or is there a better approach besides deploying two separate images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to package javascript content with a Quarkus application is to use the [Quinoa extension](https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-quinoa/dev/). It saves you the trouble of deciding on a folder structure, handles live reload proxying during development, and also packaging for production (even for native builds).

To add the extension (assuming maven):

```
./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="io.quarkiverse.quinoa:quarkus-quinoa"
```

Then put your Angular content in `src/main/webui` (*not* `META-INF/resources`). That should be enough for `quarkus dev` and a production build to both work. To try your application, visit it on the usual Quarkus port, `http://localhost:8080/'.

If needed, the `application.properties` can be configured with the port and folder names, but that's not usually necessary with popular frameworks.

Comment: It did help a lot, but when I deploy the app, the web pages are not being copied. Even if I run `quarkus build` and then `java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`, I am not able to access the frontend. I noticed during the build process that the jar is created before Quinoa.